# How to add another Text at the end of Text when Text has numberOfLines prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I want to add another text (clickable) which should be also clickable at the end of `<Text>` component so what I basically mean is I should be able to click a button which is at the end of text but the `<Text>` also must have `numberOfLines={2}` at the same time
please see example below is exactly similar to the one that I want;

[image: example]

What I tried was like below; It puts Read More at the third line what I want is it should be at the end of the second line

```
<View>
    <Text
      numberOfLines={2}
      ellipsizeMode={'tail'}
      style={{
        fontSize: 12,
        color: '#3f3f3f',
      }}>
      {data[0].commentBody}
    </Text>
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 12,
          color: 'blue',
        }}>
        Read more
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

Is there any way to achieve this ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: chech this https://reactnativecode.com/show-add-hyperlink-clickable-text/

Comment: there is no problem adding hyperlink, the problem is adding it at the end of the line even though It is set numberOfLines={2} in someway I should put it there a text or button which is fixed. At the same time text will be in the short version of it. Afterwards I will implement a function to see whole text named Read More

Comment: so you want to make it part of the first text?

Comment: It can be part of it, perhaps yes it is an option. It is okay if it they are separated too. But finally, Blue text must be at the end in a Text component which is limited to be 2 lines